# Autoresponders and GDPR - do they comply with the law?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, email

Would it be GDPR compliant to have an autoresponder request opt-in permission?

For example, a customer makes an enquiry by sending an email to the company in question. The company in question then sends the customer an automated email confirming receipt of their enquiry and inviting them to join a mailing list via an opt-in button.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be GDPR compliant to have an autoresponder request opt-in permission?

Yes. This case is specifically covered by Article 6 (1) b:

> processing is necessary for the performance of a contract to which the data subject is party or in order to take steps at the request of the data subject prior to entering into a contract

Here the "contract" is the agreement to be on the mailing list.